# Youtube video crops when loading it using StageWebView

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

When loading Youtube videos through the StageWebView Air component I need the video to be scaled down to the viewport size, displaying black bars is ok, however what I end up seeing is a cropped version of the original size of the video instead.

I'm not seeing any extra parameters that I could use, the API seems to be very limited.

Any ideas how to play the video so even if the source is larger I can resize it to the viewport size?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I display Youtube as shown in this **[other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694826/play-a-youtube-video-inside-an-air-app-as3/35711654#35711654)** (but that loads a Flash Player version, which you may not want). PS: Remember it's use `.com/v/VID_ID` for Flash Player or use `.com/embed/VID_ID` for HTML5 Player.

> Any ideas how to play the video so even if the source is larger I can
>   resize it to the viewport size?.

You say you have similar code as the Android example posted as Answer? Why not try to open an `iframe` instead since that would allow a resize option?

An example of a custom size Youtube iframe...

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ VID +"?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To open within iframe you'd have to make a dynamic webpage by code. Code below is **untested** but is based on **[this idea](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1094062?tstart=0)** from Adobe forums. Just a starting point you could adjust / fix...

```
var html_Dynamic : String;

html_Dynamic = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" +
                "<html>" +
                    "<body>" +
                        "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" +
                            VID + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n" +  "</iframe>\n";
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
```

Comment: It worked, partially, full of issues though, like the "play" button being too small, or once the suggested videos appeared they were also too small and when I clicked in one of them the next video was huge. Dunno, I don't like this approach, I ended up using VideoTexture, but yeah, this solved the issue I guess.

Comment: Is that the `iframe` approach you mean? I didnt test that one but suggested it. Might need tweaking via URL options etc. The **[other option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35711654/2057709)** of using a Flash-based YTube player might be better and you don't need stageWebView for that, just a movieclip container and resize with AS3 code...

Comment: But I don't think the flash-based one is gonna work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for Android give it a try :(it resize the page size )

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.system.Capabilities;

this.visible = false ;

var webView: StageWebView = new StageWebView();



webView.stage = stage;



function videoing(VID): void {/// VID is the video id
     stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);

    var vidLink:String = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ VID +"?autoplay=1" ;
    trace(vidLink);
    webView = new StageWebView();
    webView.stage = this.stage;
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(-(stage.stageHeight/2)+100,0, stage.stageHeight*2+40 , stage.stageWidth*2 - 160);
    webView.loadURL(vidLink);
    this.stage.focus = stage;
}


//////////////// dispose the video ///////////////////////

exit_btn.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_OptionsMenuHandler);

function fl_OptionsMenuHandler(event: KeyboardEvent = null ): void {
    if ((event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) && (webView)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        webView.stage = null;
        webView.dispose();
        webView = null ;
        stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.PORTRAIT);
    }   
}
```

On Android it needs to add

```
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have, but I still see the cropped video.